# Kong: How to list routes by service and limit size?

Tags: http, lua, kong

I'm trying to list all the routes for a service and limit the return size:

```
"GET /services/get-headers/routes?size=3 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8001"
```

But I'm getting an error that says:

```
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/endpoints.lua:122: size must be a number
```

I'm fairly convinced that this is a bug but I don't know Lua well enough to debug the Kong source code. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

**Full stack trace:**

```
2018/09/23 16:07:35 [error] 64#0: *1056076 lua coroutine: runtime error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/endpoints.lua:122: size must be a number
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/init.lua:48: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/init.lua:41>
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/endpoints.lua:122: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/endpoints.lua:111>
coroutine 1:
    [C]: in function 'resume'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:393: in function 'handler'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:130: in function 'resolve'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:161: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:159>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:159: in function 'dispatch'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/nginx.lua:215: in function 'serve_admin_api'
    content_by_lua(nginx-kong.conf:175):2: in function <content_by_lua(nginx-kong.conf:175):1>, client: 172.22.0.1, server: kong_admin, request: "GET /services/get-headers/routes?size=3 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8001"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.konghq.com/0.14.x/admin-api/#list-routes-associated-to-a-service does not show that `size` is an accepted request querystring parameter.